# warnings.filterwarnings() doesn't work to suppress ConvergenceWarning of SGDClassifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, google-colaboratory, sgdclassifier

I was testing the Scikit-learn package's `SGDClassifier`'s accuracy according to the change of the `max_iter` property. I also knew that the testing `max_iter` values are small so there would be a bunch of `ConvergenceWarning`, so I added a code to ignore those warnings.
(Testing on Google colab interface, using a local runtime(Jupyter notebook, WSL2 on Windows 11))

```py
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings(action='ignore')        # <----

from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier

for _seq in range(5, 20 + 1, 5):
    sc = SGDClassifier(loss = "log_loss", max_iter = _seq, random_state = 42)
    scores = cross_validate(sc, train_scaled, train_target, n_jobs = -1)
    print(f"""max_iter: {_seq}, scores = {np.mean(scores["test_score"])}""")
```

Unfortunately, the code didn't work and the unnecessary warnings filled all over the console, and bothered me looking at the change in the model performances.

```
/home/knightchaser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_stochastic_gradient.py:702: ConvergenceWarning: Maximum number of iteration reached before convergence. Consider increasing max_iter to improve the fit.
  warnings.warn(
/home/knightchaser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_stochastic_gradient.py:702: ConvergenceWarning: Maximum number of iteration reached before convergence. Consider increasing max_iter to improve the fit.
  warnings.warn(
/home/knightchaser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_stochastic_gradient.py:702: ConvergenceWarning: Maximum number of iteration reached before convergence. Consider increasing max_iter to improve the fit.
  warnings.warn(
/home/knightchaser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_stochastic_gradient.py:702: ConvergenceWarning: Maximum number of iteration reached before convergence. Consider increasing max_iter to improve the fit.
  warnings.warn(
/home/knightchaser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_stochastic_gradient.py:702: ConvergenceWarning: Maximum number of iteration reached before convergence. Consider increasing max_iter to improve the fit.
  warnings.warn(
max_iter: 5, scores = 0.8196000000000001
...(abbreviated)...
```

Is there a way to suppress those annoying and unnecessary warning messages? I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
```

OR:

```
import logging, sys
logging.disable(sys.maxsize)
```

Comment: I'm sorry but it doesn't work. (I already tried that too before asking a question.)

The generated logs are completely the same:
`/home/knightchaser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_stochastic_gradient.py:702: ConvergenceWarning: Maximum number of iteration reached before convergence. Consider increasing max_iter to improve the fit.
  warnings.warn(`

Comment: Maybe try the following: import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)

Comment: By the way, the warning you are getting can be supressed if you actually increase the "max_iter".

Comment: Fortunately, the second option that uses `logging` and `sys` perfectly worked for me. Thanks.

P.S.) It seems that the installation status also impacts the warning suppression. Due to other issues, I inevitably reinstalled the entire WSL2 and jupyter notebook sets, and now both my first code and your answers work.